# error compiling java program

Tags: java

when I compile any java code. I get error. Compiling the program using command line

c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>javac exampleop.java
error: error reading C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;  error in opening zip file
1 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java Runtime Environment seems busted. It'd be pertinent to reinstall it before continuing with any compilation jobs.

Comment: ... and, ideally, run a system scan for OS and hardware corruption. This is one of those "can't happens" that implies inconsistent system state.

Comment: @Rak Glad to help! Best of luck to you.